# gke ingress in front of ingress nginx

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I know this question has been asked already, but there nether was an answer to it ( [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57456652/how-to-use-gke-ingress-along-with-nginx-ingress) ). I have the same demand as in this question and I know how to manage the multiple ingress.

My current issue is that if I create an ingress in front of the nginx ingress controller, the resource targeting is always bad because the ingress-nginx health check is not at '/' but at '/healthz' so for the lb the resource is unavailable.

Does anyone has an idea on how to resolve this health check issue that I currently have?

I am following 2 ideas I have but for now it's not working:

- Use a backendConfig resource for the health check on the ingress
- Move the health check path to '/' in the controller (I don't really think that's a good idea but when out of ideas)

Do someone has a valid solution to this?

Comment: As you can see at the [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57459860/12428794): "Is not possible to point an `Ingress` to another `Ingress`". Was something changed during 2 years?

Comment: As said in my question, there was no answer, meaning that I did take a look and it's not an answer, the guy does not undersantad what he is speaking about. An Ingress is a resource, and an ingress controller is a pod...

Comment: @night-gold I think we can all agree that changing the healthcheck to /  won't be a good idea. Assuming, that you want to use `GKE Ingress` to pass traffic to `NGINX Ingress controller` (which could be used as`Ingress` resource but exposed on `NodePort` type of `Service`) you can do it with the `backendConfig`. Some time ago I wrote an answer which explains process for Istio. I'd reckon you can use it and replicate some parts of it for your `nginx-ingress`: [Stackoverflow.com: When I specify NodePort service as Ingress backend ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68340143/12257134)

Comment: @DawidKruk Did you manage to prevent the issue of the ip assigned to the ingress created? Currently it works but it's targeting the ip of the service and not the ingress ip.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. Could you elaborate on it more?

Comment: The  issue with adding an ingress in front of the ingress-controller is that you can't get your public ip to use with other tools like external-dns to create dns entries dynamically... So to answer my question, you can't do it... have to do that another way.

Answer (score 1):

The comment of Dawid is right.

I tested the backendConfig conf to resolve my issue and now everything is green on the GCP console. I still have some issues with the certs, but that's another problem.

In my case I didn't need to add a service in nodeport as I'm using a private cluster with ip aliasing and in that case a clusterIp service is enough to get to the pods.

For those who are looking for the answer, I did something like that in the end:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 30
    healthyThreshold: 2
    unhealthyThreshold: 3
    port: 80
    requestPath: /healthz
    timeoutSec: 10
```